# Right RegEx Syntax

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, match, regex-negation, nsregularexpression

I want to match this String:

```
<Array value="Default">
<Element value="5"/>
```

I tried with Negative Lookahead:

```
^((?!^\<Array value\=\"[a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜ]+\"\>).)
^((?!^\<Element value\=\"[0-9]+\"\/\>).)*$
```

For example, If I delete the token '>' then the match will be true. But in every case is false.

If I try this match

```
^((?!^\<Array value\=\"[a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜ]+\"\>).)*$
```

to this String (where I've delete the token '>')

```
<Array value="Default"
```

then comes out that is true. So I think the failure is that the two lines of this Regular Expressions

```
^((?!^\<Array value\=\"[a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜ]+\"\>).)
^((?!^\<Element value\=\"[0-9]+\"\/\>).)*$
```

are combined false.

Have anyone any solution for my problem?

Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: What regex flavour do you use (from what programming language)? And what exactly do you want in your result? It would be easier to match the entire string and use groups to access the values than to use lookaheads and only match the values.

Comment: I use Java. I want to test if these String has the correct syntax and no wrong letter or something like else in it. For Example "<Array valu=" isn't allowed because the attribute of Array MUST only be "value" and not "valu"

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if any solved your problem. You can do this by clicking the grey tick symbol on the left of one of them.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** I don't think you need Negative Lookahead to match the whole string. You could try:

```
<Array\s+value="[^"]+">\s+<Element\s+value="[^"]+"\/>
```

[REGEX 101 DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aO6nD3/2)

Comment: You could replace `[^"]+` with `.+?` and your escaping of double quote characters is inconsistent. You should also be more friendly with where you allow or require spaces.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the inconsistent issue of the double quote. There is a difference between `[^"]+` and `.+?`; the latter won't match newline character.

Comment: There's a flag that triggers if a dot `.` matches newline characters as well or not. With that, `.+?` works as well if there's a linebreak in between. However, I would not expect one in this special case here.

Comment: This works. But what I need to do when I want to match every line. For example, this string:
    `<Array value="Default">
    <Element value="8"/>
    <Element value="7"/>`

Comment: Thank you very much. What I have to do when this string is closing by `</Array>`? Something like this `<Array value="Default"> <Element value="8"/> <Element value="7"/> </Array>`

Comment: This link works, but when I delete the token `/` by `Element` then it's also true. Something like that `<Element value="7" >`. What I have to do when I want to check if `Element` have the closing Slash? And how I escape the string correct in Java?

Comment: This works fine. My last question is what characters I have to escape in Java? Whatever I try, every time Eclipse says, that is invalid escaped..

Comment: Now I have found another case. What I have to do when I want to catch that the Array don't have Elements. Something like this `Array name="default"/>`

Comment: Now we close the bracket of Array in the End with this `</Array>`. But what I have to do when the `<Array>` has no children and closing already in the beginning, something like that: `<Array name="Default"/>` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this pattern to get the two values as groups in the resulting match. Note that you might have to set the multiline flag of your regex implementation.

```
^\s*<\s*Array\s+value\s*=\s*"(.+?)"\s*>\s*<\s*Element\s+value\s*=\s*"(.+?)"\s*/?\s*>\s*$
```